# Java: reconnection on a socket sometimes gives error

Tags: java, client, socketexception, reconnect

I am making a prototype client & server so that I can understand how to handle reconnects.
The server ought to create a serversocket and listen forever.  A client may connect, send its data, and close its socket but it will not send a "I'm done and closing" type message to the server.  For this reason, the server gets a `EOFException` when it does a `readByte()` since the remote client has closed.  In the error handler for the `EOFException`, it will close the socket and open a new one.

Here's the problem:  The client sometimes gets a `SocketWriteError` when it does the `outputStream.write()` call even after it successfully opens the socket/inputstream/outpustream.  It may have something to do with the frequency that I'm opening and closing these sockets.  One interesting thing is that the client does an arbitrary number of writes/close/reconnects before crapping out.  It will sometimes crap out on the first reconnect, other times it will take 50 reconnects before seeing the `SocketWriteError`.

Here's the error on the client side:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
       at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
       at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
       at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:115)
       at bytebuffertest.Client.main(Client.java:37)
```

Here are some snippets of code:

SERVER:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Server x = new Server();
    x.initialize();
}

private void initialize()
{
    ServerSocket s;
    InputStream is;
    DataInputStream dis;
    while (true) //ADDED THIS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    {
        try
        {
            s = new ServerSocket(4448);
            s.setSoTimeout(0);
            s.setReuseAddress(true);
            is = s.accept().getInputStream();
            System.out.println("accepted client");
            dis = new DataInputStream(is);
            try
            {

                byte input = dis.readByte();
                System.out.println("read: " + input);
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception");
                dis.close();
                is.close();
                s.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("ioexception");
        }
    }
}
```

CLIENT:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Socket s;
    OutputStream os;
    try
    {
        s = new Socket("localhost", 4448);
        s.setKeepAlive(true);
        s.setReuseAddress(true);
        os = s.getOutputStream();
        int counter = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                os.write((byte) counter++);
                os.flush();

                os.close();
                s.close();

                s = new Socket("localhost", 4448);
                s.setKeepAlive(true);
                s.setReuseAddress(true);
                os = s.getOutputStream();
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.err.println("ERROR: reconnecting...");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("ERROR: could not connect");
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to properly reconnect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't close the ServerSocket on an error, just .accept() a new connection.

What I normally do is each time ServerSocket.accept() returns a Socket, I spawn off a thread to handle sending and receiving from that Socket.  That way you're ready to start accepting a new connection as soon as somebody wants to connect to you.

Comment: Yes, I believe this is the answer.  Thank you!